# Call multiple subprocess commands and restart any if child completed

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

Infinitely run several Windows CMD commands (until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) and restart any process that was complete.

```py
from subprocess import Popen

commands = ["ping 1.1.1.1 -n 10", "ping 8.8.8.8"]

procs = [Popen(i, shell=True) for i in commands]

for p in procs:
    p.wait()
```

I've replaced my commands with ping as artificial "sleep" commands. In my case, I have many commands that can run for an arbitrary duration. What I want to accomplish is:

1. Run python file and call N commands (already accomplished in above code)
2. In the meantime check if any of these commands have completed and restart them
3. Repeat until I terminate manually (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>)

If possible, I would like to have a delay between each consecutive command call to prevent overloading the server (my commands include web requests)

I'm not very familiar with parallel coding, any direction is appreciated.

**UPDATE** after @Charles Duffy's comment

```py
import subprocess
import threading

commands = ["ping 1.1.1.1 -n 10", "ping 8.8.8.8"]


def thread_function(cmd):
    while True:
        subprocess.run(cmd)


for cmd in commands:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(cmd,))
    thread.start()
```

I think this is working as intended. In many online examples of threading I see the use of `thread.join()` but that seems to be needed when you want to wait for a thread to finish.. but I don't really care about that.. Therefore I don't need `thread.join()` anywhere in my code, correct?

Comment: Start a thread for each command. Have those threads use `subprocess.run()`, or other blocking calls, in a loop.

Comment: BTW, `shell=True` is even more expensive here than usual, since using it means you're starting new shell processes over and over and over. Consider making your argument lists be stored as lists rather than strings so you don't need it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you, please see my edit. I think it's correct now?

Comment: To work with `shell=False`, you want `['ping', '1.1.1.1', '-n', '10']`. I'm not evaluating the threading correctness at this time (may look at it in a few hours when in back from my morning bike ride and breakfast).

Comment: I have done that and works perfectly, however, and this is my naive assumption, it works because `ping` is an actual program that gets called. If you wanted to use a builtin such as `echo` you need `shell=True`.

Comment: First, there's an external command version of `echo`, so it's still available with `shell=False`. Second, anything you might do in a shell built-in you could also do with Python's standard library, so there's very little point to starting a shell for said work.